# Нужна ли правка предложения?

Tags: стилистика, редактура

**Немало воды утекло с тех пор, как была опубликована в газете нижеприведенная статья, но ничего не изменилось: прочитав публикацию, толпы желающих отнюдь не ринулись в одночасье собирать рюкзаки, а лишь улыбнулись, удивляясь чудаковатости автора.**
(Имеется в виду, что так было 10 лет назад, так остается и теперь.)

Понятно ли я выразился или что-то нужно поправить? Как выглядит со стороны?

Answer (score 1):

1. После двоеточия не раскрыто, как проявляется отсутствие изменений, а показано только, что было в начале. Поэтому неубедительно выглядит "*Немало воды утекло - (но) в одночасье не ринулись*".
2. Действующее лицо "*толпы*
   " (которые не ринулись) не подходит в качестве читателя и улыбающейся сущности.

Предлагаемый вариант:

> Немало воды утекло с тех пор, как была опубликована в газете
>   приводимая ниже статья, но ничего не изменилось: прочитав публикацию,
>   люди *и тогда* не бросались толпами в одночасье собирать рюкзаки, да и
>   *сейчас* читатели лишь улыбаются, удивляясь чудаковатости автора.

Comment: Так уже лучше, только окончание предложения нужно поменять, поскольку старую статью я цитирую в новой книге и ещё не знаю, а только предполагаю реакцию:  "...да и сейчас читатели, наверняка, лишь улыбнутся ..."

Comment: @Alex_ander, действие деепричастия должно совпадать с действием глагола сказуемого, а вас не совпадает.

Comment: Оно должно совпадать у обеих частей речи с _производителем действия_ (это соблюдается), время же действия деепричастия может _предшествовать_ действию глагола (обратный порядок следования бы неверным).

Comment: Не только. Оно обозначает время не по отношению к моменту речи, а по отношению к моменту совершения другого действия, выраженного глаголом-сказуемым (относительное время).

Answer (score 1):

**В качестве варианта:**

Немало воды утекло с тех пор, как была опубликована в газете нижеприведенная статья, но **ничегО не изменилось**: прочитав публикацию, толпы желающих   **не рИнулись** в одночасье собирать рюкзаки, а читатели, возможно,  лишь **удивИлись** чудаковатости автора.

В тексте поставлены ударения на словах, которые надо выделить при чтении текста.

Comment: Но это не материал для доклада, а текст подготавливаемой к публикации книги. "Выделить интонацией" невозможно, такой вариант исключается.

Comment: Это я для Вас ставлю ударение, чтобы объяснить обоснованность такой правки текста. Он должен быть информативным (ничего лишнего), но при этом выразительным (при чтении тоническим ударением выделяются ключевые слова).

Answer (score 1):

Немало воды утекло с тех пор, как была опубликована в газете нижеприведенная статья, но ничего не изменилось: ***сегодня, как и тогда,   10 лет назад***, прочитав публикацию, толпы желающих отнюдь не ринулись в одночасье собирать рюкзаки, а лишь улыбнулись, удивляясь чудаковатости автора.

**На мой взгляд, не хватало только этого уточнения.**